# BitmapFont in libGDX become squares after hiding and showing screen

Tags: android, libgdx

My android app written on libGDX has a lot of text. I use FreeTypeFontGenerator to create a font:

```
public static BitmapFont setupHandWritingFont() {
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/handwriting.ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 36;
    parameter.genMipMaps = true;
    parameter.magFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
    parameter.color = Color.BLACK;
    parameter.characters = "абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789][_!$%#@|\\/?-+=()*&.;:,{}\"´`'<>";
    BitmapFont font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    generator.dispose();
    return font;
}
```

After some actions, which hide the screen for some time (such as showing ad or hiding the application) text transforms into squares. It happens very often, but not every time.

Text looks like this:
Wrong displaying of text
[image]

Instead of this:
Right displaying of text

[image]

Did anybody face this problem before? What may I try to do?

Comment: @Squiddie, I don't dispose font very often, but I have a static instance of BitmapFont which might be the reason of problem. I will reload this instance in resume methods. Thank you for idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this problem when I added premultiply alpha blending to batch.  You may have this because of using somewhere fade action (select box maybe?).

Try to add follow line right before drawing your font: 
`batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`